# Deleting a document based off of it's ObjectId

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm building the backend for a personal website using MongoDB and PHP, and at the moment I'm programming in a remove post feature.

At the moment I'm trying to keep it really basic, so to delete a document, I'm just making it so that the id has to be entered into a textbox.

This is what my code looks like. I simplified it down by hardcoding in the key to try to get it working before making it all dynamic.

```
<?php
    $conn = new Mongo();

    $db = $conn->selectDB("TARDISMaker");

    $query = array(
        "_id" => "ObjectId(\"56789a13c7192f67038b4567\")"
    );

    $db->p_entry->remove($query);
?>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with mongodb's php driver, but if your code isn't working try getting rid of the quotes around the _id. `"_id" => ObjectId(\"56789a13c7192f67038b4567\")`

Comment: @DerekSoike Thanks for responding! That's something that I already tried, but I did it again just to double check. In the apache logs, I got the error `Use of undefined constant _id - assumed '_id'`